# For the Dungeon of the Mad Mage adventure, how is a room's ceiling height determined?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dungeon, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

As a player I am playing in the *Dungeon of the Mad Mage* adventure. On page 11, it describes how to determine [ceiling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/undermountain-overview#Ceilings) height for rooms:

> A room's ceiling is at least as high as the room is wide, often higher. If a room's ceiling isn't specified in the text, assume it's the minimum height.

What dimension do we use to figure this out? For example: a room is 30 feet (N-S) by 40 feet (E-W), with a door on the North wall and a door on the West wall.

Would this room be 30 feet or 40 feet "wide" (and thus 30 feet tall)? Assume the room height is not otherwise specified.

What if the room is odd shaped?

Comment: Relevant question on [What is the source for 5e defaulting to plain English readings of non-game terms?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135039/what-is-the-source-for-5e-defaulting-to-plain-english-readings-of-non-game-terms)

Comment: You can create a link in the comment by copying the URL and putting it in `[link_text](http://example.com)` which creates this -> [text](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135039/what-is-the-source-for-5e-defaulting-to-plain-english-readings-of-non-game-terms) :) You can see more [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumption: The question is actually "How can I determine the height of a room where the height is not explicitly stated and the room is an irregular shape?"

## Unfortunately, ask the DM

Often, a room's height doesn't matter. Many DM's (myself included) forget about ceilings until it actually comes up in play.

But if you're a connoisseur of ceilings, a renaissance-man of roofs, or a tourist of tops, you'll likely keep an eye out for such details, in case it comes in handy.

[Matt Vincent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158138/34716) has an excellent answer about "normally" shaped rooms, but in any case where "length" and "width" aren't easily measurable ('s' shaped rooms, '@' shaped rooms, 'etc' shaped rooms, etc.), you're just going to have to ask the DM.

Over time (***Maybe*** before the end of the module), your DM will start learning to include that information, and you won't have to ask.

---

It may be worth noting that If you're trying to play a highly tactical game where the height of a room is critically important to your play style, you and your DM (or the other players) might not be all on the same page. A mini-session-zero revisit to address this could help out.

Comment: This is the addition I was looking for.

Answer (score 45):

### Width is the Shorter Side

[According to](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/793506314148163584) 5e's lead designer: "*Unless the rules explicitly expand, narrow, or completely redefine a word, that word retains the meaning it has in idiomatic English*". What is "Width" in English?

- In [geometry](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/mathematics-statistics/difference-between-length-and-width/), length pertains to the longest side of the
  rectangle while width is the shorter side.
- Per Dictonary.com's [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/length) of Length: "*the measure of the greatest dimension of a plane or solid figure.*"
- Per Merriam-webster's [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/length) of Length: "*the longer or longest dimension of an object*"
- Per the Wiktionary's [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/length) of Length: "*The distance measured
  along the longest dimension of an object.*"
- Per the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length) for Length: "*Length is commonly
  understood to mean the most extended dimension of an object.*"

These standard definitions are consistent with how the terms are used in the rule books. Examples:

- An [ankheg](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ankheg.htm) *"spits acid in a line that is 30 feet long and 5 feet wide"*
- A [Black pudding](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ooze.htm) or [Air Elemental](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elemental.htm) *"can move through a space as narrow as 1 inch wide"*
- A [Black Dragon](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonsChromatic.htm) *"exhales acid in a 90-foot line that is 10 feet wide"*
- The [Gust of Wind](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm) spell creates *"A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide"*

If you are concerned that the writer's accidentally misused the word, their intent seems be backed up with:

- A long, thin room (say 20'x100) is unlikely to have a tall (100') ceiling
- In Dungeon of the Mad Mage p.11: "*assume it's the minimum height*" would not lead one to use the longest side.

### In Summary

[Dungeon of the Mad Mage (p. 11)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/undermountain-overview#Ceilings):

> A room's ceiling is *at least* as high as the room is wide, often higher. If a room's ceiling isn't specified in the text, assume it's the minimum height.

This indicates that a 30'x40' room would indeed be 30' tall, assuming the room height is not otherwise specified.

For oddly shaped rooms: the DM will have to make a call. I'd recommend approximating a rectangle that the room, or discrete sections of the room, would fit into. Example: a 30'x40' oval room with an adjacent 10'x10' alcove might have a 30' ceiling, except in the alcove (where it might have a 10' ceiling).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100164/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-vincent-for-the-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage-adventure).