# What information is available about the intended mathematics of D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, statistics, game-design

D&D 5e was heavily play-tested prior to its release. I have heard (but have not verified) that, at low levels, the hit rate of the attack rolls of PCs was intentionally optimized to be approximately 2 in 3. Presumably, this probability was chosen deliberately by WotC, then – through simulations, models, and tests – features were added/removed/tweaked until it was realized according to some metric. I am interested in information about this process.
What information, if any, is publicly available about the play-testing process for D&D 5e and about the outcomes (such as this 2/3 hit-rate) that were optimized for during play-testing?

I **am not** asking *why* any rules are the way they are or *why* any of the particular math was used. I **am** asking *what* math was used and *what* information has been published/leaked/discussed about it.

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76327/) is similar to my question. Its top answer links to pages documenting the design goals of D&D, including some details of the play-testing process (for example, [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130511024707/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20121112)). However that question is about the general design goals while this question is about the math and the methods of simulating/modeling/quantifying the game. It does to link to relevant information, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### None

Play testing for D&D Next which became 5e was subject to a non-disclosure agreement. WotC know but they aren’t saying.

Comment: I mostly assumed this was the answer but wanted some confirmation of it, thanks!

Comment: Is this really relevant? All the actual playtesting has been discussed all over the internet. You can easily get different playtesting documents. And you'd be hard-pressed to convince anyone the NDA is even still enforceable. But those aren't related to the internal decisions WotC made when they changed various rules between playtest versions. Things like [this article](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/fifth-edition-feedback-survey) and [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20130511024707/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20121112) aren't covered by the NDA.

Comment: @MichaelS if you have better information please supply an answer, the best refutation would be a contribution.