# Can a level 2 Warlock take one level in rogue, then continue advancing as a warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, rogue, character-advancement

I recently "upgraded" to D&D 5th edition. I decided to play a warlock. However, now I would like to be proficient in Stealth, and a warlock can not have this proficiency.

I am Warlock level 2. Is it possible to now multiclass into rogue, take just one rogue level, and then continue advancing as a warlock afterwards?

My stats are as follows: Str 11, Dex 18, Con 13, Int 11, Wis 6, Cha 18.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. Please add the system-and-edition tag to your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. What RPG and edition are you playing? By "5.0", do you mean D&D 5e? If so, you can indicate this by editing the [dnd-5e] tag into your post. Furthermore, can you clarify what your actual question is? Even with a system specified, the question will likely need to be clearer to be answerable. What's the connection between taking a level of rogue and being proficient in Stealth?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try to be more clear.

Comment: What books do you own / have you read ?

Comment: Just players handbook, dnd-5e and all handbooks of dnd-2e

Comment: Please tell us your stats, specifically your Charisma and Dexterity, as these will dictate whether or not you are able to multiclass as a Warlock and a Rogue.

Comment: str 11 , dex 18, con 13, int 11, wis 6, cha 18

Comment: Though this doesn't address your specific question, there IS another way to gain stealth proficiency.  The feat "Skilled" could also be useful.  See: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46305/how-can-you-gain-proficiency-in-a-skill-after-level-1

Comment: @julio "3.5" is the only D&D edition that is listed with a decimal ("."). :)

Comment: There's also the "Skilled" feat that could be taken at level 4

Answer (score 24):

### Yes, you can multiclass and take one Rogue level

You can multi-class just to gain 1 level of Rogue since you meet the requirements. As noted [in the basic Multiclassing rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Multiclassing), you need a Dexterity of 13 and Charisma of 13 in order to multi-class from Warlock into a Rogue.

**Alternative**

Have you looked at backgrounds?

This is normally something done at character creation, but you could have a word with your DM to see if he is amenable to changing your character.

Each background tends to give proficiency in two skills (as well as tools and/or language).  If all you really want is proficiency in Stealth, then you could find a background that grants this such as the [Criminal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Criminal) background.  If you can't find a background that you like you could also work with your DM to [make a custom background](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65842/22566) (see PHB p. 124-126) that fits your character and grants proficiency in Stealth.

Comment: Edited to account for the stats being provided, and while I was in there tossed in a few other things.  Please review to make sure you are content.

Comment: Please note that multiclassing, while widely available in nearly every single D&D 5e campaign, is still technically an "optional" rule that a DM may not wish to use.

Comment: It might be worth noting that [the multiclassing rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#MulticlassingProficiencies) state that multiclassing into bard also gives one proficiency in any skill, just as multiclassing into rogue grants proficiency in any one class skill.

Comment: seems like the "alternative" part should have more emphasis, as it's likely to provide a superior outcome for the OP.

Answer (score 8):

The multiclassing rules are explained in the Player's Handbook on page 163 :

> Multiclassing lets you combine classes together [...].  Your DM
>   decides whether these options are available in a campaign.

So check with your DM if they are OK allowing this.

> Multiclassing allows you to gain levels in multiple classes. Doing so
>   lets you mix the abilities of those classes to realize a character
>   concept that might not be reflected in one of the standard class
>   options. With this rule, you have the option of gaining a level in a
>   new class whenever you advance in level, instead of gaining a level in
>   your current class. Your levels in all your classes are added together
>   to determine your character level. For example, if you have three
>   levels in wizard and two in fighter, you're a 5th-level character.

So you can take 2 levels of Warlock, then 1 level of rogue (as long as you meet the 13 DEX prerequisite for multiclassing into Rogue and the 13 CHA needed to multiclass out of warlock)(thanks @Someone_Evil).

Doing so will give you the following proficiencies :

> Light armor, one skill from the class's skill list, thieves' tools

As well as expertise in two skills, Thieves' Cant, and Sneak Attack (thanks @Davo)

Comment: This also yields Expertise in two skills, Thieves' Cant, and Sneak Attack.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answers already posted:
When you gain a Level, you may (*assuming your GM is allowing multi-classing*), choose **any** Class that you qualify for (by virtue of 13+ Ability Scores). 
[Multi-classing Rules here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Multiclassing)

So you may begin as a Warlock, take x Warlock levels, then a Rogue Level, and then more Warlock levels (and maybe a Sorcerer level, if you so choose, as you meet the 13 CHA*).

You can swap back and forth between any classes that you qualify for. 
e.g. if you somehow got your STR to 13, you could then take a level of Barbarian, and then more Warlock, or Rogue levels!

*Not that I would recommend this, but it's your character :)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out to OP where in the rules the prerequisites for multiclassing are listed. Also: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). There's no need to leave an edit note; anyone who's interested can view the revision history.

Comment: Note that 13 Dex will allow Fighter MC as well (Str not required).